# JSON.NET Line serialization winrt

Tags: serialization, windows-8, line, json.net, observablecollection

I'm having some trouble with serializing a ObservableCollection of Lines (Shape). I'm developing for Windows RT and I'm using JSON.NET v5.02. I'm getting the following exception for the code below:

```
ObservableCollection<Line> lines;
//some code
string linesString = JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(lines); // problem
```

> An exception of type `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error getting value from 'X1' on
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Is this a bug and is there a possible workaround?

Comment: `lines` isn't initialized in your example.

Comment: a sample project can be downloaded at the following link:
http://speedy.sh/ByHWx/JsonNetProblem.rar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a cross thread problem. When using `await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(lines);` that function will be executed in another thread (not the UI thread). Since a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line` is a UIElement and was created in the UI (main) thread you can't access the properties of the object in another thread. The solution would be to convert it to a simpler object that doesn't have this restrictions.

Besides, a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line` contains a lot of information, Visibility, IsEnabled etc, I think you would only need the X1, X2, Y1 and Y2. So you could just use this:

```
string s = await JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(lines
             .Select(l => new 
                     {
                         l.X1,
                         l.X2,
                         l.Y1,
                         l.Y2
                     }).ToArray());
```

In this way, you get the properties you need in your UI (main) thread. Then pass that array to the serialize function. This way it works.

`string s` would now contain:

> [{"X1":20.0,"X2":20.0,"Y1":40.0,"Y2":40.0},{"X1":20.0,"X2":20.0,"Y1":40.0,"Y2":40.0},{"X1":20.0,"X2":20.0,"Y1":40.0,"Y2":40.0},{"X1":20.0,"X2":20.0,"Y1":40.0,"Y2":40.0}]

Comment: Don't forget to use the `.ToArray()` if you don't you create a statemachine with the `.Select` A statemachine will be executed when it is needed, that is in the `SerializeObjectAsync` which is in another thread. By calling `.ToArray()` you force the statemachine to run and create an array in the UI thread.

Comment: Hi@SynerCoder Can I use your solution for my problem please let me know thanks in advance...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105051/save-information-of-line-and-images

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Json.Net allow serializing framework class object. I tried with this.

```
public class CustomLine
{
    public double X1 { get; set; }
    public double X2 { get; set; }
    public double Y1 { get; set; }
    public double Y2 { get; set; }
}
```

I Changed the `Line` to `CustomLine` line. If you want to use `Line` class then retrieve properties `X1, X2, Y1, Y2` and then assign it to `CustomLine` class properties.