# Save information of Line and Images

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am developing Drawing App for Windows store.I want to save information of Line and Images in XML drawn in the screen How can I do that please give me suggestion?

[image]

Comment: My problem is that I want to use information of Line and Image in another Page i think it will be possible when I save all the info of Line and Image drawn in screen..But not able to think logic please help me

Comment: Have you tried to use XML/JSON serialization ? [JSON.NET Line serialization winrt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944553/json-net-line-serialization-winrt)

Comment: Yes, you have to get the xml note which is previously drawn line, then you can update it.

Comment: ok, I am posting my comment as answer. Please mark it as answer, comment there if you need any further help. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use XML/JSON serialization for line. You can save image as base64 strings

[JSON.NET Line serialization winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944553/json-net-line-serialization-winrt)

[How to convert Base64 string to image, then bind it to GridView in a Metro Style App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516856/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-image-then-bind-it-to-gridview-in-a-metro-style/10904403#10904403)

[Read Base64 image with C# in a Windows 8 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855722/read-base64-image-with-c-sharp-in-a-windows-8-app)